# Ruby Regex: Insert space if set of characters encountered

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like your help formulating a regex in Ruby.

I would like to insert a space after the literal `\par` in a string only if these conditions are met:

1. `\par` is not followed by `d\`, so not `\pard\`.
2. `\par` is not followed by a `\`, so not `\par\`.
3. And `\par` should not be followed by space, so not `\par`.

Here is what I came up with:

`my_string.gsub!(/(?<=\\par).(?!(\d\\)|(\S)|(\\))/, ' ')`, but this does not work for me at the moment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. Try changing the regex as

```
(?<=\\par)(?!d\\|\s|\\)
```

**Changes made**

- Drop the `.` between the look arounds. This is required as the `.` would be matched and consumed by engine
- `\d` to `d` as you intend to match `d` and not digits (`\d`)
- `\S` to `s` You have already used a negative look ahead. so `\s` with the negation ensurs that there is no space following `\par`

[**Rubular Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/g0wuzCt5LN)

**OR**

shorter version would be

```
(?<=\\par)(?!d?\\|\s)
```

Comment: Couldn't one reduce this to this? `(?<=\\par)(?!(d?\\|\s))`

Comment: @DavidFaber, yes I think [that's](http://rubular.com/r/kBrcrO2yLP) a little better.

Comment: @DavidFaber Yeah. Thats even shorter !!. Added in answer. Thank you :)

Comment: You don't need the inner parenthesis in the negative lookahead.

Comment: @CarySwoveland They are actually useless. Included just to group. Removed anyways. Thanks

Comment: I know all do not share my view, but I advise to never include anything that is not needed, redundant parentheses and `self.` being prime examples. The reason is that readers--especially less-experienced Rubyists--may assume the superfluous bits are needed.  If they are confused by the absence of such bits, they will quickly figure it out and learn something they need to know.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way, which only uses a negative lookahead:

```
def stuff_space_maybe(s)
  s.gsub(/\\par(?!\s|d?\\)/,'\par ')
end

stuff_space_maybe("let's \\part\\y!")
  #=> "let's \\par t\\y!" 
stuff_space_maybe("let's \\pard\\y!")
  #=> "let's \\pard\\y!" 
stuff_space_maybe("let's \\par\\y!")
  #=> "let's \\par\\y!" 
stuff_space_maybe("let's \\par\\ty!")
  #=> "let's \\par\\ty!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused by what exactly you want, this?

```
\\par(?!d\\)(?!\\)(?! ).
```